# Does IIS 7 have limit of simultaneous requests?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7

Does IIS 7 have some limit of simultaneous requests? I'm using Windows Server 2008.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, but since we're talking about IIS, the answer isn't that easy. Depending on your application, the limit can be overridden in the code (goooo ASP.NET with maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU/maxConcurrentThreadsPerCPU) or otherwise, you'll need to change the [appConcurrentRequestLimit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347568.aspx) property in the IIS Settings Schema.

The default is 5000, but some people recommend bumping that up substantially (like by a factor of 20. I only use IIS when I have to, so YMMV).